# changing list into string to compare

Tags: python, python-2.7

```
all_courses=open("E:/we/aa.txt","r").readlines()
completed_ones=open("E:/we/aaa.txt","r")
read_completed_ones=completed_ones.readlines()
my_dict={}
my_dict["completed courses"]=read_completed_ones
for line in all_courses:
    if line.strip().startswith("#"):
        continue
    splitted=line.split(",")
    print read_completed_ones
    courses_remaining=splitted[2]
     print read_completed_ones[3]
    if courses_remaining==("") and splitted[0] != read_completed_ones:
            1==1
```

i had a problem with the last if statement, the read_completed_ones in that statement is a list, and of course because string != a list its always true, because i'm trying to put the splitted which is not in read_completed_ones in a dict .

P.S 1==1 is just a statement i put so i don't get any error while trying
thanks for the help.

Comment: use `pass` instead of `1==1`

Comment: I think you want `read_completed_set = set(read_completed_ones)`, then test for membership with `splitted[0] in read_completed_set`. Here's the [documentation on sets](http://docs.python.org/2/library/sets.html)

Comment: @Cuadue it gives the same output, it prints all the splitted[0] even if its in read_completed_ones

Comment: Can you post a few lines of each file; `aa.txt` and `aaa.txt`?

Answer (score 0):

You can use join to make a string from a list of strings, like this:

```
...splitted[0] != ''.join(read_completed_ones):
```

Comment: it gives the same result because i think join makes it all one whole string